# Angular - NgRx selector notifying about data update

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Is there a way to write some sort of a "**data updated**" selector when I don't care about the updated data itself?
Imagine a reducer:

```
const initialState: SomeReducer = {
  dataInQuestion: Array<SomeDto>,
  ...
}
```

Then some *action -> effect -> action -> reducer* chain will update `dataInQuestion` and I want to be notified about that while I don't care about the new data. I came up with this but with just a short glance one must admit that it is questionable at least and it breaks pure function principle.

```
const selectDataInQuestion => createSelector(selectSometing, (state: SomeReducer) => state.dataInQuestion);
const getDataInQuestionUpdate => createSelector(selectDataInQuestion, () => Math.random()); 
// Math.random() - To ensure that new value is always returned :)
```

Of course I can use selector for `dataInQuestion` and omit any value assign I was just curious if there is a way do so. Or if there is some best practice for that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your requirement, it can be boiled down to the most recent action, i.e., the one triggering the reducer.
As such, you can just listen to this very action (using the `ActionsSubject` provided via dependency injection) and do your thing.

Comment: I know about this option though it seems bit weird to me. I kind of consider this Action subject to be effects only thing.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Just a custom I guess.